# How to create an event emitter with elixir, the otp way

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp, eventemitter

What is the best way in elixir to create a foreground process that tick on every given amount of time?

My main problem is that an approach like:

```
defmoulde Ticker do
  def tick do
    do_something()
    :timer.sleep(1000)
    tick
  end
end
```

works, but is wrong by design. It's definitely not ticking every second, but every second PLUS the time for do_something() to complete.
I could spawn a process to handle the "something" but still there is a small lag.

Also, I'm trying to build a mix app, there is some GenServers involved, and a main foreground process (the one I'm asking here) that should call the servers every x seconds. Is there an otp way of doing this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think `timer:apply_interval/4` should suit your needs. It is used something like this:

```
defmodule Tick do
  def tick do
    IO.inspect(:tick)
  end
end

:timer.apply_interval(:timer.seconds(1), Tick, :tick, [])
```

The arguments in order are the interval, a module name, the function to call and the arguments to call it with. Then you can send messages to your `GenServers` inside that function. Check out the full documentation here: [apply_interval/4](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/timer.html#apply_interval-4)

Another thing to consider is that if your `tick` function is only ever sending simple messages to some `GenServers` then it is probably *extremely* fast, so your implementation might be OK, once wrapped in a `Task` and plugged into the supervision tree (if you don't care about the potential slight drift that is).

Comment: I care about the potential time drift. How would I avoid any time drift?

Comment: `apply_interval` should be pretty decent, but the docs only state that "The time-outs are not exact, but are at least as long as requested".

Answer (score 4):

If you prefer sending a message instead of calling a function at a given interval, you can use [`:timer.send_interval/3`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/timer.html#send_interval-3)

E.g. if you want to send a message to a `GenServer` every second as OP mentions in their answer, you could do the following:

```
:timer.send_interval(:timer.seconds(1), target_pid, :tick)
```

Where `target_pid` is the PID of the `GenServer` you want to send a message to. Then you can handle this message in your `GenServer` like this:

```
def handle_info(:tick, state) do
  do_something()
  {:noreply, state}
end
```